# next.js not posting to db when using variables, but works when hardcoded

Tags: node.js, express, next.js13

I have an next.js frontend project that I am busy with to try and learn new libraries and technologies. I've coded and tested my express backend using Postman. All my api endpoints work with no issue.

I am trying to collect data using a form and passing it to the body:

```
try {
   const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(employeeData),
   });
      
   if (response.ok) {
      console.log('Employee saved successfully');
   } else {
      console.error('Error saving employee:', response.statusText);
      console.log('Response Body:', await response.json());
   }
} catch (error) {
   console.error('Error saving employee:', error);
}
```

When printing the `employeeData` to the console, all the relevant info is there and is correct, but is not being added to the db and I am getting a status 200 as my response. I'm using mongoDB and cors.

I did some research, reading documentation and other forms for solutions, but wasn't able to find why this is happening and what might be possible solutions.

Thus, I tried to hardcode the values:

```
const formData = {
   name: 'John',
   surname: 'Doe',
   telephone: '0123456789',
   email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
   manager: 'Manager A',
   status: true,
};

try {
   const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
   });
      
   if (response.ok) {
      console.log('Employee saved successfully');
   } else {
      console.error('Error saving employee:', response.statusText);
      console.log('Response Body:', await response.json());
   }
} catch (error) {
   console.error('Error saving employee:', error);
}
```

The hardcoded values did get added to the db, but I would like to have my input on the form be saved.

Edit:

Here is the full file addEmployee.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import axios from 'axios';

import MenuBar from '@/components/MenuBar';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function addEmployee() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [managerOptions, setManagerOptions] = useState([]);
    const [employeeData, setEmployeeData] = useState({
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        telephone: '',
        email: '',
        manager: '',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('Employee data:', response.data);
                setManagerOptions(
                    response.data.map(
                    (employee) => `${employee.name} ${employee.surname}`
                    )
                );
            })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error fetching employee data:', error);
        });
    }, []);

    const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setEmployeeData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, [name]: value }));
    };

    const handleManagerChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        setEmployeeData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, manager: event.target.value as string }));
    };

    const handleButtonClick = async (option: string) => {
        switch (option) {
            case 'Save':

                if(employeeData.name === '' || employeeData.surname === '' || employeeData.telephone === '' || employeeData.email === '') {
                    alert("Required fields are not filled in!");
                    break;
                };

                try {
                    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(employeeData),
                    });
      
                    if (response.ok) {
                      console.log('Employee saved successfully');
                      console.log(response);
                    } else {
                      console.error('Error saving employee:', response.statusText);
                      console.log('Response Body:', await response.json());
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error saving employee:', error);
                }
                router.push('/employee');
                break;
            case 'Cancel':
                router.push('/employee');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    return (
        <Container>
            <MenuBar />
            
            <Container maxWidth="md">
                <Box mt={4} mb={2}>
                <Typography variant="h5">Create Employee</Typography>
                </Box>
                <Box border={1} borderColor="grey.400" p={2} borderRadius={4}>
                <form>
                    <Box mb={2}>
                        <TextField label="Name*" fullWidth name="name" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                    </Box>
                    <Box mb={2}>
                        <TextField label="Surname*" fullWidth name="surname" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                    </Box>
                    <Box mb={2}>
                        <TextField label="Telephone Number*" fullWidth name="telephone" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                    </Box>
                    <Box mb={2}>
                        <TextField label="Email Address*" fullWidth name="email" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                    </Box>
                    <Box mb={2}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth>
                        <InputLabel>Manager</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            value={employeeData.manager}
                            onChange={handleManagerChange}
                            displayEmpty
                        >
                            {managerOptions.map(manager => (
                                <MenuItem key={manager} value={manager}>
                                {manager}
                                </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Box>
                    <Button type="button" variant="contained" color="inherit" onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Save')}>
                        Save
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="inherit" onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Cancel')}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                </form>
                </Box>
            </Container>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Comment: You would need to add the code where you get `employeeData` from the inputs. The fact it saves to the db with a hardcoded object being sent suggests your issue in specifically related to how you create that `employeeData` variable.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have edited the questions to include the full file, incase there might be something else.